# npm try to use proxy after have removed it

Tags: npm, http-proxy

I have set proxy for my npm, and now when I removed it

```
npm config rm http-proxy
```

I can't install packages.
npm try to use the proxy

Answer (score 0):

Check your .npmrc file to see what's in there?